# CommonJS module returning undefined when is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, undefined, commonjs

I'm totally new to modular JS and never used any of the pattern before. I'm writing a project where it got up to 400+ lines of code and I want to manage it better by separating things in different modules. I chose to use commonJS modules because I already use webpack. Now I putted my first function in a different module and exported it like this:

```
//init.js file
var initt = function () {
  octaveNumber = document.getElementById("octaveNum");
  audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
  osc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  volume = audioCtx.createGain();
  filter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
  osc.connect(filter);
  volume.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  booleanVal = false;
  osc.frequency.value = dial.value
  osc.start();
  gainDisplay.innerHTML = gainSlider.value;
  noteSetOscFreq()
  octaveUpClick()
  octaveDownClick()
  waveFormSelector()
}

module.exports = initt;
```

in my main JS file I required it

```
var messages = require('./init');
```

and finally called the function in an If statement where it belongs:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("presetsArr") {
  messages.initt;
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting `Cannot read property 'gain' of undefined` in the console which means that Init module is not initialising variables and other things as it supposed. When I put that whole function back without using commonJS modules, it works just fine. I know it might be something with returning the values, but I can't put my hands on it. Nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

messages.initt() X

messages() √

Comment: Now I don't get the undefined problem, thank you. It's off topic but I get another error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'AudioParam': The provided float value is non-finite.` Could it do something with synchronous problem of commonjs? Because like I said, if I don't use modules, everything works fine.

Comment: Because there is no complete code, I can not guarantee my answer。

I think you may look at some commonjs specification document，there may be scope issues。

as you see,i am not good at english,hope you can understand what i said